# API for Speex codec in Flash/Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, audio, air, speex

With AIR 2 allowing access to mic data, it's possible to save/process audio locally. Adobe provides a WAVWriter example but is there any API access to the Speex codec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, audio is completely decompressed while in memory, but is automatically compressed natively when sent through a NetStream. As far as I know, no API is exposed to use the native compressor. Currently, there's also no port for the speex compressor in AS3 or Haxe. So I guess your only options are to:

1. live with WAV
2. port and encoder to AS3 (for example [JSpeex](http://jspeex.sourceforge.net/))
3. use an external tool to do the work for you. I am not sure whether the Air internal browser support Java applets. If it did, you could write an applet, that uses JSpeex to do the desired conversion. If you need file system access, or to bind ports (for the air runtime to connect to), you will need to [sign your applet](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/rsa_signing.html).