# How to play speex encoded audio in Flash player?

Tags: apache-flex, audio, flash, microphone, speex

I am able to record sound from microphone, encode it using SPEEX and write into ByteArray. I want to play it back.
If I try using Sound object the audio is messed up. 
Speex uses 16kHz for encoding and Sound Object needs 44.1kHz for playing audio. How am I supposed to play this encoded sound.

Please help!!

*- Pat*

Comment: possible duplicate of [API for Speex codec in Flash/Flex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652232/api-for-speex-codec-in-flash-flex)

Comment: I voted to close because I feel your question is already sufficiently answered on that other post.  You, basically, need an ActionScript codec for SPEEX to play it back.

Comment: Adobe claims that they support Speex codec in recent versions of Flash Player. Why should I use an external ActionScript code for Speex codec?!

Comment: Thanks Jeffry for your comment, but I don't find my solution.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com [link](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/825956)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a browser or Air based application?

The reason I ask is because Speex is only playable through an FLV container.  It's a one way encode that is made to be streamed through a media player like FMS or Wowza. Here's what you need to do for both cases.

**If browser based**
There's no way to playing it locally.  You're going to have to stream it to a media server which then returns an FLV file for you to play on the client.

**If Air based**
You can wrap the speex audio into an FLV container and play it locally.  Use this library to write the FLV locally: http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/simpleflvwriteras-as3-class-to-create-flvs/

Comment: Thanks a lot.. :) Mine is a browser based application.